# tinyMCE 3.5 blur event fires when toolbar buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, tinymce

I've been trying to use the following method to capture when a tinyMCE field is blurred as has been mentioned in numerous SO posts and on tinyMCE's site as well:

```
tinyMCE.dom.Event.add(ed.getDoc(), 'blur', onBlur);
```

However, I've noticed that this event gets fired even when a user clicks a button on the tinyMCE toolbar (e.g. Bold, Italicize, Underline). Is there any way to prevent this. I've tried a couple of different solutions for checking to see the target element that was clicked, but haven't come up with anything that works consistently across all browsers.

Tried:

```
function onBlur(e) {
    if($(e.target.activeElement).hasClass('mceIcon')) return;
    // do something
}

function onBlur(e) {
    if($(e.target.activeElement).parents('#' + ed.editorContainer).length > 0) return;
    // do something
}
```

Also, I've noticed that this seems to be an IE8 (possibly other versions of IE as well) specific bug. Here's a JSFiddle showing the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/klinden/8rs4j The console logs all instances of blur getting called.